# controller & model name ambiguity in code igniter 2.0.2

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller, hmvc

Following is the scenario:
I've integrated HMVC in CodeIgniter 2.0.2. Created a module with following structure.

/application/modules/login

/application/modules/login/controllers

/application/modules/login/controllers/login.php

/application/modules/login/models/login.php

/application/modules/login/views/login_form.php

controller/login.php code

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
       //load login form view
    }
    public function authenticate(){
       $model = $this->load->model('login'); //tried with Login
       $model->validate(); //shows error here
    }
}
```

/views/login_form.php

```
<form name='LoginForm' method='post' action='/login/authenticate'>
```

/models/login.php

```
class Login extends CI_Model{
  public function validate(){
    echo $this->input->post('EmailId');
    echo $this->input->post('Pword');
  }
}
```

output:
**got error indicating undefined method Login::validate()**
When created validate() method in controller Login it works. But it shouldn't happen.. even though I'm loading a model with name Login why it points to Login Controller.

Can anyone could help me out. The way I did is it correct? Suggestions welcomed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading and accessing your model incorrectly.  Take a look at the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading) for more examples.

Change your `authenticate()` method to:

```
public function authenticate() {
    $this->load->model('login');
    $this->login->validate();
}
```